# jQuery check if any text input has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to ask if there's a better way in jQuery to select multiple text input then check if any of them has a value. Here's my code:

```
if ($("#reference").val() != "" || $("#pin").val() != "" || $("#fName").val() != "" || $("#mName").val() != "" || $("#datepicker").val() != "") { /*logic goes here */ }
```

Comment: @Priyajain, For what?

Comment: @Priyajain OP want to check if at least one input got a value, not if all of them are empty. Please don't mislead him.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
if ($("#reference,#pin,#fName,#mName,#datepicker").filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).length > 0) {
  //..
}
```

Using a common function like the following would make it reusable:

```
function hasValue(elem) {
    return $(elem).filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).length > 0;
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
hasValue("#my-input-id");
```

Answer (score 12):

Try jQuery [each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
 $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
     var text_value=$(this).val();
     if(text_value!='')
       {
        console.log('Value exist');
        }

   })
```

Comment: The OP may not have all fields with input tag!

Comment: @C-link,he says "select multiple text input"

Answer (score 6):

The problem with getting the `length` property on `filter()` is that jQuery will evaluate every single element in the collection, just to populate a count when all we care about is whether the value is greater than zero.

None of the current answers and even jQuery's own [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/), and [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) make use of short circuiting as soon as the criteria is met.

You can define a simple extension method called `.any()` like this:

```js
jQuery.fn.any = function(filter){ 
    for (i=0 ; i<this.length ; i++) {
     if (filter.call(this[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

And then pass in a filtering function like this:

```js
var someInputsEmpty = $("#reference,#pin,#fName,#mName,#datepicker").any(function() { 
    return this.value == '';
});
```

```js
jQuery.fn.any = function(filter){ 
 for (i=0 ; i<this.length ; i++) {
    if (filter.call(this[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

$(function() {
 
  var gotMatch = $(":input").any(function() { 
                   return this.value == 'hi';
                 });

  if (gotMatch) {
    console.log("Hello to you too!");
  } else {
   console.log("Why don't you say Hi!");
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
```

#### Further Reading:

- [Jquery check form to see if any inputs has value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10413716/1366033)
- [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31044/1366033)
- [Jquery check form to see if any inputs has value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10413716/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
if (!$("#id").val().length == 0))
```

Comment: Or if it's a complete piece of code, use code blocks by indenting four spaces, as I've just done.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/rr2ss/1/

Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/rr2ss/12/

```
$(function() {

    // Check value of each and every input element....
    // Which you can of course change to be more specific, like: $('#myForm input')
    $( "input" ).val(function( i, val ) {

        // Return the console log IF value is not empty
        // value=" " still counts as "not empty", because technically it isn't
        // You could of course replace the console.log(); with anything you'd like
        val && console.log('not empty: input-' + (++i) );

        // Note that you don't have to return val if you don't  want to, it's just for show in this case.
        return val

    });

});
```