# Check if input type text Contains value in div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one div in which their are 3 input fields of type text , I want to show alert on button click if any of the 3 input fields contain value.

```
<div id="userdiv">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="text" name="company" />
<input type="text" name="area" /><br />
<button id="btn1">Search</button>
</div>
```

How can I check if any of the field contains value using jquery ?

Comment: Please take a little while to try coming up with an answer on your own! If you've already tried and can't figure it out, edit your question to include your attempt(s), and we can gladly help you out.

Comment: you can google any number of examples of using JS / jQuery to validate data. Did you do _any_ research? This isn't a free do-my-thinking service. We'll help you if you have an actual problem with some actual code.

Comment: If you spent a time searching this, you would have found your answer much faster than typing the question of your post,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery check if any text input has value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294112/jquery-check-if-any-text-input-has-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to loop over all the `input` fields and get then check the value for each input field to check non-empty.

```js
$('#btn1').click(function(){
  var input = $('#userdiv input[type="text"]');
  var found = false;
  for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if($(input[i]).val().trim() !== ''){
      found = true;
      alert('Non empty');
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
    alert('all fields are empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userdiv">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="company" />
  <input type="text" name="area" /><br />
  <button id="btn1">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So much code for a simple `if ($('#userdiv input[type="text"]').filter(function() { return $(this).val().trim(); }).length > 0) alert("nope");`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    var myCondition = false;
    $('#userdiv').find('input').each(function() {
        if (!myCondition && $(this).val().includes('my_search_string')) myCondition = true;
    });

    if (myCondition) console.log('Found it!');
});
```

We can iterate through each `<input>` to check if any of them contain a specific string. If you want to only see if they contain **something**, then we can replace `$(this).val().includes('my_search_string')` with `$(this).val().length` since that will return FALSE unless the length is > 0